# Why border of <tr> not showing in IE?

Tags: css, xhtml

Why border of `tfoot tr:first-child` not showing in IE. I'm checking in IE7.

`font-weight:bold; background:yellow` is showing in IE but border not

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}

table tfoot tr:first-child {
    font-weight:bold;
    background:yellow;
    border-top:2px solid red; 
    border-bottom:2px solid red;
}
```

HTML

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th align="left" scope="col">XXXX</th>
   <th align="right" scope="col">XXXX</th>
   <th align="right" scope="col">XXXX</th>
   <th align="right" scope="col">XXXX</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
  <tfoot>
  <tr>
   <td colspan="3">XXXX</td>
   <td align="right">XXX</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
   <td colspan="4">XXX</td>
   </tr>
 </tfoot>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td align="left">XXXX</td>
   <td align="right">XXXX</td>
   <td align="right">XXXX</td>
   <td align="right">XXXX</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

update:

i'm  using this doctype

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html lang="en" xml:lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

Comment: Please post the HTML for your `<table>` too.

Comment: @fmark: Stack Overflow and Doctype are run by different companies. It is perfectly fine and normal for this question to be here.

Comment: have you checked other browsers? i'm pretty sure that TR doesn't support borders... just set your TDs to accept borders

Comment: @Jason it does properly work in FF, Chrome and IE (after adding a DOCTYPE) under Win and Linux (IE not under Linux of course!).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would avoid styling `tr` elements because they don't really "exist" as such, apart from for semantic reasons. You're better off targeting the table cells themselves, with something like this:

```
table tfoot tr:first-child th,
table tfoot tr:first-child td {
    font-weight:bold;
    background:yellow;
    border-top:2px solid red; 
    border-bottom:2px solid red;
}
```

Also, since you are targeting directly nested elements, you can use the child selector, which is faster for browsers to parse (they only have to search one level up/down).

```
table > tfoot > tr:first-child > th,
table > tfoot > tr:first-child > td {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_pseudo_first-child.asp

> Note: For :first-child to work in IE, a `DOCTYPE` must be declared

Add something like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

And it should work

Answer (score 0):

Give position as relative for tr class, which will fix.

tfoot tr {position:relative; border-bottom:solid 1px #ccc; }