# <th> Border not working in IE

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer, xhtml

I have the follow code to fix the header of the table while scrolling down the page.

I don't know why, but in fiddle are not working in FF :(

See code: http://jsfiddle.net/S63dy/

If you try outside fiddle it's works like a charm in FF, but the borders aren't showing on IE.

Im using IE9 and IE Tester (and i tried on another machine with IE8).

I try to use a header just by styling a row and using  inside, but no borders on IE too.

Can someone help me ?

Thanks and sorry the bad english

Comment: Add the border to TDs, not TRs

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why border of <tr> not showing in IE?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2832260/why-border-of-tr-not-showing-in-ie)

Comment: Do not rely on fiddle too much.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery - how to freeze table header and allow scrolling of the rest of the rows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/983031/jquery-how-to-freeze-table-header-and-allow-scrolling-of-the-rest-of-the-rows)

Comment: @Jleagle: I tried to add border on TDs, TRs, THs, the whole table.
Nothing works or the scumbag IE.

And Tony my question is not about freeze the header while scrolling.
Thanks guys, but I'm still stuck on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CSS seems ok, but you are setting the `visibility` of the whole cloned table to `hidden` - it looks like this is preventing the border rendering.

You could change this:

```
$("#clone").css({
    visibility: 'hidden'
});
```

to:

```
$("#clone").children().not('thead').css({
    visibility: 'hidden'
});
```

See [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jfrej/S63dy/5/).

Or even better just remove the unnecessary `tbody` and don't touch the `visibility` at all.

Or clone the `thead` on its own - this will take less memory if you are dealing with a huge table.

Comment: Thank you so much, It works!
BTW i tried to clone only the thead but it mess with the width :(

Answer (score 0):

You should not be styling the TH within your CSS.

TH is a header cell.

TD cells are for data which should work fine for you.

Comment: I treid to use the first row (with TDs not THs inside it) as the header. It's works too, but on IE it still not showing the border.