# padding not behaving like I expect them to in a table row

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

When I `hover` over this, the first `td` moves. But why? I'd like for it to remain stationary.

```css
.q-tr:hover {
    border-left: 2px solid #35ccea;
    padding-left: -2px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">      
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr class = 'q-tr'>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
        <th>Email</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr class = 'q-tr'>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class = 'q-tr'>
        <td>Mary</td>
        <td>Moe</td>
        <td>mary@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class = 'q-tr'>
        <td>July</td>
        <td>Dooley</td>
        <td>july@example.com</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Remove your `padding:-2px` and add `box-sizing : border-box` to your css

Comment: `padding` is inside the element (and border), you should use `margin`, though it won't work on table rows and cells ... Vucko has a working solution for you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because tables with the collapsing border model don't have padding at all ([reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19069129/1763929)).

**Update** - thanks @LGSon for mentioning that it won't work for IE - [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2834645/1763929).

So, instead of targeting the `tr`, target the first cell in each `tr`:

```
.q-tr > td:first-child {
    border-left: 2px solid transparent;
}

.q-tr:hover > td:first-child {
  border-left: 2px solid #35ccea;  
}
```

[Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/aEKn7Q4YPt)

Comment: That's really smart. Thanks!

Comment: why is that the case?

Comment: @nachime In early days (even today actually) the interpretation of the specs. weren't the same, hence different browsers renders elements (the table element particularly) different, so what IE lacks will IE lack since now they have Edge, where it work with hover on table rows

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
 table.table tr th, table.table tr td {

    border-left: 1px solid transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `padding-left: -2px;` when you hover. It will work fine.